# DIY 3 V -16 V, 300 watt boost converter for ultracapacitors

Tags: boost, supercapacitor, buck-boost, tesla-coil, step-up

I am trying to build a power supply for a portable Tesla coil project using 6 × 3000 farad supercapacitors in series (16.2 V @ 500 F). I am trying to maximize the usability of the supercapacitor as the voltage drops drastically under load as opposed to batteries which supply constant voltage, and using a boost converter will hopefully do so. Any plans available for a build that can boost 3 VDC to 16 VDC @ 20 amperes will be appreciated.

Edit: initially I was planning for 800 watts but realized that is too dangerous of an output plus it will shorten the life of the capacitors, so 300 watts is somewhat more manageable

Comment: "Plans" as in some form of future intention? Will your capacitors supply 300 amps?

Comment: as in schematics, as far as i know they can supply 300 amps

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using a battery?